# Put a Picturebox over a flow layout panel without it being affected by the flow. I can just put it everywher I want including over the panel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, picturebox, flowlayoutpanel

Is it possible to put a picturebox over a flowlayoutpanel without it being affected by the flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You simply have to make sure that it's parent is the form rather then the FLP.  If you drag the `PictureBox` in the designer then you'll probably end up dropping in on the FLP.  Instead, add it to the form and then set the `Location` property manually to move it.  You can then manipulate the z-order in the Document Outline window if necessary to make sure the `PictureBox` is in front, or you can just right-click one of the controls and select "Send to Back" or "Bring to Front".